# 2 data frames, 2 different styles of naming the same person, how to make them similar?

Tags: r, search, split, rename

I have a two datasets. In one dataset fist name, second name and last name are written in different variables. 
for instance:

```
 ID            firstname        second name          last name
 12            john             arnold               doe
 14            jerry            k                    wildlife
```

In the second one they are written in one variable:

```
 ID            name
 12            john arnold doe
 14            jerry k wildlife
```

Now I want to be able to find these people from dataset two (full names) in dataset one (seperate names). 
A couple of problems that i have are:

- not all names occur in both dataset,
- not all names have a middle initial,
- not all names have IDs so I cannot search on that alone either.

so the question is, could someone suggest a command to split the names in first/second/last name? secondly would someone know how to search for these names with a simple command, something like:

```
    df<-df.old[grepl("firstname", df.old$firstname, ignore.cases=T) & grepl("secondname", df.old$secondname,ignore.cases=T) & grepl("lastname", df.old$lastname, ignore.cases=T),]
```

any suggestions?

Dirk

Comment: May be `do.call(paste, df1[-1])==df2$name` or use `match` to get the index  after `pasting`.  Based on the example provided, the rows are the same in both datasets.  What would be the expected result?  It is better to provide an example with all the cases and an expected result based on that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `separate` from `tidyr` package.

```
separate(df2, name, into=c("firstname", "secondname", "last name"), " ") 
# ID firstname secondname last name
#1 12      john     arnold       doe
#2 14     jerry          k  wildlife
```

For missing middlenames, if lastname can be classified as middle name,

```
df2 <- data.frame(ID=c(12, 14), name=c("john arnold doe", "jerry wildlife"))
library(splitstackshape)
cSplit(df2, 2, sep = " ")# this reads "split 2nd column by white space"
#   ID name_1   name_2 name_3
#1: 12   john   arnold    doe
#2: 14  jerry wildlife     NA
```

`name_1` corresponds to `first name`, `name_2` to `middle name`

Comment: it just does not work for people without a middle name (second name) such as John Smith, any idea on how to handle the missing middle name? it is also fine if last name is classified as middle name.

Comment: @DirkvanDooren See the update. Hope it achieves what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

***Sample Data ***

```
df2 <- data.frame(ID=c(12, 14), name=c("john arnold doe", "jerry k wildlife"))
```

Split names by space

```
df2 <- cbind(df2$ID, data.frame(do.call(rbind, strsplit(as.character(df2$name), " "))))
names(df2) <- c("ID", "firstname", "second name", "last name")
df2
```

Join the two data frames by first name and last or id.